# Automatically Add Appropriate Exception Handling in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception

I have an interesting question. I have a large Android project in Eclipse. When I run my application, some exceptions occur, like NullPointer, OutOfMemory, FileNotFound, and it crashes.

I want to handle all the exceptions properly, but adding exceptions one-by-one for each line is going to be a very difficult task for such a large project.

Is there any way to do this quickly in Eclipse? Handling all the appropriate exceptions in try/catch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is just and IDE. IDE can not catch the Error or Exception of your project.

It is us (Developer) has to take care of it. Now what you are looking is catching an uncaught Exception handler. There are lot of tools paid/free available which you can integrate into our project and catch that irritating force close error.

Try 
http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-avoid-force-close-error-in-android/

My own code snippet. That will catch your uncaught exception from any Activity. You can modify it according to your need.

Note : That doesn't meant you shouldn't write Try/Catch in your code/